# How can i decode json data if i saved in array laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 two tables: one is an admission and the other is a class table. I am saving class id in admission class field of admission table by `json_encode` method.

My controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
         $inputs = $request->all();

    $admission = new Admission;
    $admission->school_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $admission->admission_classes=json_encode($inputs['admission_classes']);
    $admission->save();   

}
```

My index function

```php
public function index(Request $request) {

    $school_id= Auth::user()->id;

    $admissions= Admission::where('school_id',$school_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('frontend.index',compact('admissions','active_class'));

}
```

My view

```php
@foreach($admissions as $i => $admission)

  {{ $admission->admission_classes }}

@endforeach
```

I am getting data in this way:-

```
["1","2","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
```

But I want to get in this format:

```
Nursery,Class 1, Class2, Class3 etc
```

```html
My class controller
class Classes extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use Billable;
    use Messagable;
  
    protected $fillable = [
 'name','status'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I cant see your input, but it looks like you're saving the keys rather than the values of your original array

Comment: `$inputs` is not defined in your `store()` method.

Comment: I am assuming you have an `AdmissionClass` model. Could you show us that also?

Comment: Sorry i  forgot to add,    $inputs = $request->all();, yes I am saving key not value, and it is saving in this format ['"2",'"1",'"3",'"4",] but i want to disply in this format Nursery,Class 1, Class2, Class3 etc

Comment: class Admission extends Authenticatable
{
     protected $table = 'admissions';


 public function School()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School','school_id');
    }
    

    
}

Comment: Please add the model code to your question.

Comment: I had added my model please check

Comment: We need the Admission Class model. Not the Admission one.

Comment: Sorry sir i had updated my class model,please help

Comment: @ravi please try on  my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this would be to have a one-to-many relationship with `App\Classes`.

However, since you already have something up and running, I would probably do it like this.

First, I would cast `admission_classes` to an array. This makes sure that admission_classes will always be casted to an array whenever it is fetched. It makes it easier for us to work with it.

```
protected $casts = [
    'admission_classes' => 'array'
];
```

Finally, while fetching your admission records, you would also need to map over it and hydrate the `Classes` from its ids. This is how I'd try to achieve it.

```
$admissions = Admission::where('school_id',$school_id)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->paginate(10)
    ->map(function($admission) {
        return array_map(function($class) {
            $class = Classes::find($class); 
            return isset($class) ? $class->name : ''; 
        }, $admission->admission_classes); 
    });
```

You will notice that I wrapped the `Classes::find()` method into the `optional()` helper. This is because, in case, a record is not found, it will not fail.

Finally, to print your class names in your blade, you would do something like this:

```
implode(',', $admission->admission_classes);
```

Comment: done as you said but this error is coming  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map()

Comment: Forgot that there was a paginate at the end there. Edited my answer, could you give this a try?

Comment: Can i have your email address sir, i need your help please sir

Comment: $admissions = Admission::where('school_id',$school_id)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->paginate(10)
    ->map(function($admission) {
        return array_map(function($class) {
            return optional(Classes::find($class))->name; 
        }, $admission->admission_classes); 
    });       this is the error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\optional()

Comment: `optional()` was added in Laravel 5.6. You might be running an earlier version, in which case, you can try my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save integer value in as json array and do the following code

```
$integerIDs = array_map('intval',  $inputs['admission_classes']);
 $admission->admission_classes= json_encode($integerIDs);   

 public function index(Request $request){
    $admissions = DB::select('SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as classes FROM academy as a LEFT JOIN class c ON JSON_CONTAINS(a.classes, CAST(c.id as JSON), '$') WHERE a.school_id =2 GROUP BY a.id');

    $admissions = $this->arrayPaginator($admissions, $request);

    return view('frontend.index',compact('admissions','active_class'));
 }

 public function arrayPaginator($array, $request)
 {
       $page = Input::get('page', 1);
       $perPage = 10;
       $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;
       return new LengthAwarePaginator(array_slice($array, $offset, 
         $perPage, true), count($array), $perPage, $page,
            ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);
  }
```

I have not checked the code hope this will help u to continue.......

Comment: i dont understand sir the way you sent me.The way i had done is incorrect , if yes then please guide me